# Why Quadratic equation's root result is NaN ? (Java)

Tags: java, math

Why write out 
**The roots are NaN and NaN** in console?
I've read about NaN, but I don't find the right solution how can I repair the mistakes...
I've tried **casting to double** the **discriminant** and the **roots** but doesn't work.
Can somebody help me, where and what I need to rewrite?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Pattern newlineOrSpace = Pattern.compile(System
            .getProperty("line.separator")
            + "|\\s");
    sc.useDelimiter(newlineOrSpace);
    System.out.print("Enter a, b, c: ");
    double a = sc.nextDouble();
    double b = sc.nextDouble();
    double c = sc.nextDouble();
    // System.out.format("a = %f, b = %f, c = %f", a, b, c);

    double root1;
    double root2;
    double discriminant;
    discriminant = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
    if (discriminant > 0) {
        System.out.println("There are no real roots ");
    } else {
        root1 = (-b + discriminant) / (2 * a);
        root2 = (-b - discriminant) / (2 * a);
        System.out.println("The roots are " + root1 + " and " + root2);
    }
```

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and guess that `a` is very small, maybe even zero. What would you like the function to do in that case?

Comment: As hammar infers, but doesn't explicitly state, the discriminant D is given by D = b^2 - 4ac.  Upi... more information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Answer (score 7):

`Math.sqrt(x)` returns `NaN` when `x` is negative, which then propagates through the rest of your code. You'll want to test for negative numbers *before* taking the square root:

```
discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
if (discriminant < 0) {
    System.out.println("There are no real roots ");
} else {
    root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    System.out.println("The roots are " + root1 + " and " + root2);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking for conditions like a = 0; one root is zero, and the other is -c/b.  Easy to do, and both are real.  There are more degenerate cases to look for than just zero determinant.

Comment: Could I just suggest using Math.abs() for negative numbers? For example I want to calculate a distance and don't care if the number is negative or positive.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, let's get rid of user input as a cause for this - it's much easier if the short but complete program contains all the data we need:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        showRoots(2.0, 10.0, 2.0);
        showRoots(10.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }

    private static void showRoots(double a, double b, double c) {
        double discriminant = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
        if (discriminant > 0) {
            System.out.println("There are no real roots ");
        } else {
            double root1 = (-b + discriminant) / (2 * a);
            double root2 = (-b - discriminant) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("The roots are " + root1 + " and " + root2);
        }
    }
}
```

This shows two cases - one where there really *are* roots - but the program claims there aren't - and one where there really *aren't* real roots, but the program prints them out as NaN. When you take the square root of a negative number, the result is NaN, which is why that's being displayed.

So, the problem is how you're dealing with the discriminant. There are real roots if *b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac* is non-negative - but you've already taken the square root at that point *and* reversed the nature of the condition.

So, it should be:

```
private static void showRoots(double a, double b, double c) {
    double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (discriminant < 0) {
        System.out.println("There are no real roots ");
    } else {
        double discriminantRoot = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
        double root1 = (-b + discriminantRoot) / (2 * a);
        double root2 = (-b - discriminantRoot) / (2 * a);
        System.out.println("The roots are " + root1 + " and " + root2);
    }
}
```

Lessons to learn:

- When you want to demonstrate a problem, it helps to keep it minimal; using hard-coded values is a good way of doing this
- Be careful about the order of operations - in this case, you were trying to judge something using the wrong value because you'd taken the square root too early
- Be careful with conditions and whether or not you're getting them the right way round

EDIT: As noted in comments, there are various special cases to consider too, including when `a` is 0 which would otherwise lead to a division by 0 issue.

Comment: I'd recommend checking for conditions like a = 0; one root is zero, and the other is -c/b.  Easy to do, and both are real.  There are more degenerate cases to look for than just zero determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c; 
if (discriminant >= 0) {
    discriminant = Math.sqrt(discriminant);  
    root1 = (-b + discriminant) / (2 * a);          
    root2 = (-b - discriminant) / (2 * a);          
    System.out.println("The roots are " + root1 + " and " + root2);      
} 
else {
    System.out.println("There are no real roots ");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that when your discriminant is negative. Like for a=1,b=2,c=3. Delta = 2*2 -4*1*3 = 4 - 12 = -8

Java can't calculate square root of negative number, it doesn't know about imaginary number i.