# Android Studio Quadratic Equation NaN

Tags: java

I am trying to make a quadratic equation solver on android. I have a basic setup working but unless I enter a perfect quadratic it will output NaN.

```
TextView answerField1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
TextView answerField2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
EditText fieldA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aTextField);
EditText fieldB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bTextField);
EditText fieldC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cTextField);
Double aString = Double.parseDouble(fieldA.getText().toString());
Double bString = Double.parseDouble(fieldB.getText().toString());
Double cString = Double.parseDouble(fieldC.getText().toString());
Double answer1 = ((-1 * bString) + Math.sqrt(((bString * bString) - (4 * aString * cString))))/(2 * aString);
Double answer2 = ((-1 * bString) - Math.sqrt(((bString * bString) - (4 * aString * cString))))/(2 * aString);
answerField1.setText("" + answer1);
answerField2.setText("" + answer2);
```

Is there a way to output a raw value w/ decimals?

Comment: Are you looking for `String.format`?

Comment: What does this have to do with NaN?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Quadratic equation's root result is NaN ? (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461803/why-quadratic-equations-root-result-is-nan-java)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I managed to fix it through the link from Slanec.

Comment: Yep, the problem was not the code, but the math. It's possible for a quadratic equation to have no real solutions, or even just one solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by creating an if statement that checks if the discriminant is greater that 0.

```
if(((b*b)-4*a*c) < 0){
        System.out.println("No real answers");

    }
```

This should eliminate any problems you had.